# Date Format in mongoose, mongodb and node application

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

First time question and newbie coder so treat me like I'm 5 years old.

Okay so as I'm learning, I'm horrible at trying to understand how to use documentation to fix my problems.  I'm setting up a node application with mongodb as the backend.  The starting point is it is something that will pull via api baseball game results into a database (date, teams, scores).  The problem I've ran into is I want to take in dates.  When I do it comes back with the generic 1970's date and I can't seem to get it to just keep the formatted date.  The source of the data and the date will be given programmatically and so it won't be prone to human error so I don't need date validation.  I just need it to recognize the date and keep it's format so I can find or filter on it.  The data will only have the year/month/date and not the time.

I'm setting this up in a mongoose file to load into my mongodb DB.
I've looked at https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#mongoose_Mongoose-Date information, but I'm either missing the point or not seeing what's in front of me.  Any hints on how to accept date information?

```
const GameDayStats = mongoose.model('GameDayStats', {
    Date: {
        type: Date
    },
    Home: {
        type: String
    },
    HomeScore: {
        type: Number 
    },
    Visitor: {
        type: String
    },
    VisitorScore: {
        type: Number
    }, 
    Final: {
        type: Boolean
    }
 
})
 
const game = new GameDayStats({
    Date: 2021-08-04,
    Home: 'Cardinals',
    HomeScore: 8,
    Visitor: 'Pirates',
    VisitorScore: 2,
    Final: true
})
 
game.save().then(() => {
    console.log(game)
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log('Game Stat Error!', error)
})
```

What the output looks like

```
{ 
  _id: 602e774fbee0692662ea16fa,
  Date: 1970-01-01T00:00:02.009Z, <----I want this in normal date form                            
  Home: 'Cardinals',
  HomeScore: 8,
  Visitor: 'Pirates',
  VisitorScore: 2,
  Final: true,
  __v: 0
}
```

Comment: What I've seen is that if I put the date in with single quotes it will run, but it then converts it to the longer format in the database.  Is that just what's going to happen or is there something I can add to have it keep the original formatting?

Comment: You are using `type:Date` in model that converts passed string to `JavaScript Date` and returns that format, you can either `convert returned Date to local `or store it as a `type:string` (not recommended as hard to validate and all)  in database.

Comment: don't try to store dates as the format you want to see them, let mongo store it as a date object and format it on display

Comment: @Joe Okay so leave it be inside the quotes as that's the object you are referring to correct?  Then someday down the road when I actually figure out my use case for displaying dates convert it in the node/HTML/CSS?

Comment: @ShivamSood dates will be provided by the api and not a person, so I'm not worried about validation as it will always be a constant.  Thanks for the comment! I guess I will take Joe's approach if nothing else comes up and leave it then change it when ever I come up with the display use case.